# Envio de correos a todos mis usuarios registrados

Tags: php

Quiero enviar un email a todos mis usuarios registrados al mismo tiempo, pero solo me envía al ultimo usuario.

Aquí mi código:

```
include('php/connection.php');
$sql = "select email from usuario";
    $rpt = mysqli_query($cn,$sql);

    while ($des = mysqli_fetch_array($rpt)) {
        $destinatario = $des['email'];      
    }    

    $asunto = 'hola'; 
    $cuerpo = ' 
    <html> 
    <head> 
       <title>saludos</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <h1>Hola </h1> 
    <p> 
    <b>Bienvenidos a mi correo electrónico de prueba</b>. 
    </p> 
    </body> 
    </html> 
    '; 
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n'; 
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n';
    mail($destinatario,$asunto,$cuerpo,$headers); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error en tu código es que recorres lo que te trae de *Base de Datos* pero lo almacenas en la variable `$destinatario` y por eso al terminar el ciclo solo guarda el valor del ultimo que recorrio el ciclo. Lo que deberias de hacer es meter el código del envio del correo dentro del ciclo for, como en el siguiente código:

```
include('php/connection.php');
$sql = "select email from usuario";
$rpt = mysqli_query($cn,$sql);

while ($des = mysqli_fetch_array($rpt)) {
    $destinatario = $des['email'];
    $asunto = 'hola'; 
    $cuerpo = ' 
    <html> 
        <head> 
           <title>saludos</title> 
        </head> 
        <body> 
            <h1>Hola </h1> 
            <p> 
                <b>Bienvenidos a mi correo electrónico de prueba</b>. 
            </p> 
        </body> 
    </html> '; 
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n'; 
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n';
    mail($destinatario,$asunto,$cuerpo,$headers);
}    
?>
```

Y en caso de que el cuerpo no cambien en ningun momento lo puedes realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
include('php/connection.php');
$sql = "select email from usuario";
$rpt = mysqli_query($cn,$sql);
$asunto = 'hola'; 
$cuerpo = ' 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>saludos</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1>Hola </h1> 
        <p> 
            <b>Bienvenidos a mi correo electrónico de prueba</b>. 
        </p> 
    </body> 
</html> '; 
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n'; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n';

while ($des = mysqli_fetch_array($rpt)) {
    $destinatario = $des['email'];
    mail($destinatario,$asunto,$cuerpo,$headers);
}    
?>
```

Comment: gracias amigo J. Castro, una consulta a que  se debe que no me llegue los mail a correos coorporativos

Comment: Me imagino que debe de ser por permisos pero puedes hacer una nueva pregunta para tu duda con mas detalles para que se te pueda ayudar, si te sirvio la respuesta marcala como aceptada.